# Create file from AJAX response data and force download

Tags: ajax, download, phpexcel

I need to make an AJAX call from a page, sending some JavaScript data to a PHP file, which creates a file based on that data. I then want this file to be downloaded by the user.

So is it an option, to make a force download of a file created by PHP (specifically PHPExcel in my case) via an AJAX request?

The code shown below does not yet send any JavaScript data, but does generate a file.

This is my PHP script, which creates a file using PHPExcel:

```
public function renderTasksToExcel($tasksData){


    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("TRW");
    // ...

    // Add some data

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
    // ...

    // Rename sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


    // Save Excel 2007 file
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $file = '/export.' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s').'.xlsx';
    $objWriter->save($file);

    // hotovo
   return $this->sendResponse(new FileResponse($file));
}
```

And this is AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: {plink Tasks:tasksToExcel},
     data: ajaxData,
     success:function(data){
        $('#download').html(data);
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

same with mine. but i already solve this problem,try this:
use this in your php:

`$objWriter->save('export/FileName.xls');`

and use this in your ajax call:

`$.ajax({`

```
 type: "POST",
 url: {plink Tasks:tasksToExcel},
 data: ajaxData,
 success:function(data){
    $('#download').html(data);
     var zz=document.createElement('a');
     var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
     zz.href ='htp://localhost/bengkel/backend/export/FileName.xls';
     zz.download='FileName'+'.xls';
     zz.click();
 }
```

})

simple concept,ajax cant download. then,save *xls file,and then download that file with JS.
sorry im junior programmer and my bad english..
hope this help you,good luck :)